# How to run multiple line sql from text file

Tags: mysql, sql

a file.txt have a multipe sql update.

```
update table1 set meta_url = replace(meta_url,'test1.jpg','test1.gif');
update table1 set meta_url = replace(meta_url,'test2.jpg','test2.gif');
update table1 set meta_url = replace(meta_url,'test3.jpg','test3.gif');
update table1 set meta_url = replace(meta_url,'test4.jpg','test4.gif');
update table1 set meta_url = replace(meta_url,'test5.jpg','test5.gif');
                          ...
update table1 set meta_url = replace(meta_url,'test100.jpg','test100.gif');
```

I want to create a script which allows to connect automatic, and execute all lines in file.txt at time.

the concept like that:

```
mysql -u root -p  ( user and password log automatic by script)

use databasename1;

update all line in file.txt

exit;

service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against storing the password in a file on the system.

```
mysql -u root --database=yourdatabase -p < file.sql
```

That will prompt you to enter the password and then run the SQL commands in the file.